# Application Defined and Object Defined error

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, slicers

I have a pivot with Area name. I want to extract file name using (-) hyphen separator. And select slicer Item with file name. File name extraction is working fine but, Selection not working.
Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2()
    '
    ' Macro2 Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
    '
    Spl
End Sub

Public Function Spl()
    Dim wbName As String
    Dim fileName As String
    'Get the workbook name
    wbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    'Split the workbook name by the dash character
    fileName = Split(wbName, "-")(0)
    'Call the subroutine for each slicer cache
    SelectSlicerItems "Slicer_Area", fileName
    
End Function

Sub SelectSlicerItems(slicerName As String, fileName As String)
    Dim sc As SlicerCache
    Dim si As SlicerItem
    Dim index As Integer
    'Set the slicer cache object
    Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(slicerName)
    'Loop through the slicer items
    For index = 1 To sc.SlicerCacheLevels.Count
        For Each si In sc.SlicerCacheLevels(index).SlicerItems
            If si.Name = fileName Then
                si.Selected = True
            Else
                si.Selected = False
            End If
        Next si
    Next index
End Sub
```

I want to split area name from file name and apply filter based on area name on Slicer.

**Answer:**
Due to data model we've to use in this way. Thanks for the answer link provided by another user.

```
Sub sliceit()
'
' sliceit Macro
'

'
    Dim wbName As String
    Dim fileName As String
    'Get the workbook name
    wbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    'Split the workbook name by the dash character
    fileName = Split(wbName, "-")(0)
    'Call the subroutine for each slicer cache
    
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Area").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
        "[Range].[Area].&[" + fileName + "]")
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Area1").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
        "[Table2].[Area].&[" + fileName + "]")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: si.Selected = False

Comment: You may have a look on: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51193840/17172829

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA change Slicer item selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193840/vba-change-slicer-item-selection)

Comment: Thanks.
I've added the final snippet in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Due to data model we've to use in this way. Thanks for the answer link provided by [Shrotter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17172829/shrotter)
Here is the finished code.

```
Sub sliceit()
'
' sliceit Macro
'

'
    Dim wbName As String
    Dim fileName As String
    'Get the workbook name
    wbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    'Split the workbook name by the dash character
    fileName = Split(wbName, "-")(0)
    'Call the subroutine for each slicer cache
    
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Area").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
        "[Range].[Area].&[" + fileName + "]")
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Area1").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
        "[Table2].[Area].&[" + fileName + "]")
    Sheets(Array("Summary", "TT Wise ", "DB Wise", "Route Wise ")).Select
    
End Sub
```