# Best way to approach using vba to set slicers on source workbook, then to copy & paste into target workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

Background:
We have an excel with data updated weekly by our central team.
HQ replaces the 2nd previous week data rather than just adding it. We can not change this.
For example, in calendar week 7, they add calendar week (CW) 6 of data, and they remove calendar week 4. Leaving only 2 weeks of data at a time.
It is set as a pivot table filtered via slicers.

What I want to do with vba is this:
I want to be able to run the macro, in which it selects the exact same 4 slicer items in their respective slicers, and a 5th slicer, in which it selects the top listed slicer item (the oldest CW data available).
In the end posting the filtered/sliced data into another excel to become a historical database.

Lmk if any questions: Would be a huge help.

Cheers,
Shane

I can no problem set a source and target workbook, select the data I want from the source and post to the end or where I want in the target. My problem comes when filtering via slicer. Which is our only option. Goal is to be able to just run the macro once a week, and it does it all.

Comment: Is the data setup as a range or as a data model, such as OLAP cubes? This change the syntax of how you refer to these objects. Reminds me of this question: 
 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193840/vba-change-slicer-item-selection

Comment: I am pretty sure it is set up as a range. Don't hate me if I am wrong lol...

Comment: Won't hate you, trying to help. The way you can tell is if you select any cell in the range/table, if it's a table you'll see more options appear on your ribbon such as "Query". The link I provided may steer you in the right direction. You need to add the VBA you have for this here for more guidance though, example data as well would be helpful so users understand the context of your workbook and question.

Comment: When I select a cell, the only options that appear are pivot table tools analyze and design